# Parameter 0 of method setFilterChains error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    GoogleOAuth2SuccessHandler googleOAuth2SuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/shop/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(googleOAuth2SuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        return http.build();
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

This is my SecurityConfig class which is used to handle authorisation. There is a class called GoogleOAuth2SuccessHandler for handling OAuth login which is pretty irrelevant in this context.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

These are the 3 dependencies which I'm using in pom.xml. These are all from 2023 itself.

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of method setFilterChains in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' in your configuration.
```

This is what I'm facing when I run the app. I'm not sure what the use of this repository is in my app. I've checked similar posts over here but they seem to be different kinds of errors than this one.

Comment: Could you shorten your `authorizeHttpRequests` configuration to  just the lines  causing the error?

Comment: @LeonKlute Hey thats what I dont understand like which parts are causing this error.

Comment: You could just start removing parts of the configuration until the error disappears, then you will know which part of the configuration is causing the error.

Comment: basically what the error is saying is that you have not configured the client information that is needed if you are going to login against a third party issuer like for instance google, facebook etc. you have `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` on your classpath and you have not configured the oauth2 client. Read the docs!

Answer (score 0):

spring:
security:
oauth2:
client:
registration:
google-idp:
provider: google
client-id: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID:google-client-id}
client-secret: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET:google-client-secret}
scope: openid, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
client-name: Sign in with Google
github-idp:
provider: github
client-id: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_ID:github-client-id}
client-secret: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET:github-client-secret}
scope: user:email, read:user
client-name: Sign in with GitHub
provider:
google:
user-name-attribute: email
github:
user-name-attribute: login

yml 配置你也要使用官方的demo里面的，原因是因为client配置

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have most probably not provided the `spring.security.oauth2.client` properties for the OAuth2 login: when this properties are missing, Spring Boot does not auto-configured a repository for OAuth2 client authorizations.

Many complete OAuth2 security configurations in [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/6.2.0/samples/tutorials#1-oauth2-essentials)